# Deleted all Google Calendar events by mistake (web). How to I push my local android calendar to the web?

Tags: sync, calendar, google-account, google-calendar

I just deleted ALL my events from Google Calendar (website) by mistake!

My calendar events are still intact in my Nexus 7 because I have not synchronized after the mistaken deletion.

I would like to know how can I make sure that the events in my tablet will be pushed to the web on my next sync (I fear that syncing will delete my local events)

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is for manual sync. [iCal import/export](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.aichbauer.ical&hl=en) can export your events. 
The second step would be to import those events to google (in Google Calendar -> other Calendars -> import Calendar).

Not tried it myself, but you get the idea.

Comment: To underline and clearify: *First* use the export tool to export all your calendar entries. This way you have a backup even if you mess up. After that, simply sync. If the entries are gone from your calendar, import from that file, and sync again. At the latest after that, everything should be fine again.